# How to send to the back end the changes of location in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, gps

Hi someone knows how to send the changes of locations with a backend (http post) if a have it on a stream like i show in the following part

```
  StreamSubscription<Position> positionStream = geolocator.getPositionStream(locationOptions).listen(
          (Position position) {
        print(position == null ? 'Unknown' : "Location: "+ position.latitude.toString() + ', ' + position.longitude.toString());
          });
```

I'm using goelocator packages

When i use setState all the widget reaload again and again.

```
      final Stream<Position> positionStream = Geolocator().getPositionStream(locationOptions);
      _positionStreamSubscription = positionStream.listen((Position position) => setState(() {
        _positions.add(position);
        sendCoordinate(position);

      }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dio`](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) or the [`http`](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package for sending REST API HTTP requests to your backend at any time.